# Cross module direct communication (via IP / sockets)

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

If we have two custom modules that need to communicate directly via sockets, is there a way to know what the IP address assigned to each module?

After reading [this article](https://www.tutorialworks.com/container-networking/) I was under the impression the azure-iot-edge network bridge would possibly support referencing the running module by the module name as the hostname.  This doesn't seem to work.

I guess we are trying to avoid having to scan the network or use some local storage option and don't want to join the host network so any ideas how one module that is running can find the IP of another module that is expected to be running?

Here is a picture showing the two containers I am testing with.  The one container is just an alpine instance that I can attach the console to and use to try to ping / access other containers.  I can ping by IP address but want to ping by container name instead.
[image]

Comment: It should be possible to resolve other modules by name if they are all running on the azure-iot-edge network. Have you taken steps to confirm that both modules are running on that network (and not on the host network or other)?

Comment: Affirmative, the containers are the same azure-iot-edge bridge network and i can ping from one to the other by IP, but since IPs can change, i want to ping by hostname.  I also tried setting the container options to specify the "Hostname" and it is set properly but doesn't seem to help.  Will update my thread to paste an image showing the two containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further study of this issue, it turns out the issue was the arm32v7 arm image I was using when deployed had some issues.  One of the oddities was that the date on the container was "Sun Jan  0 00:100:4174038  1900" and there were some other commands failing that should have worked.

I ended up switching over to an ubuntu image with iputils-ping installed and confirmed that the azuire-iot-edge bridge allows accessing other containers by their module name which servers as the host name, so all good here, works as expected, user error!